# Cписок изображений из ссылок

Tags: jquery, html, изображения

Имеется список вида

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link1"><img src="img01.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="link2"><img src="img02.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="link3"><img src="img03.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="link4"><img src="img04.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

При клике по любой ссылке в списке, например на третьей, добавляется `div`, в который выводятся изображения в `src` которых записывается `href` ссылок, а к изображению, порядок которого соответствует порядку кликнутой ссылки, добавляется `class="clicked"`. Вот так:

```
<div class="new div">
  <img src="link1">  
  <img src="link2">
  <img src="link3" class="clicked">
  <img src="link4">
</div>
```

Как это реализовать на jQuery ?
Вот фиддл http://jsfiddle.net/gWQVR/

Comment: для начала я бы посоветовал отказаться от ссылок, что бы не убивать клик по сслыке

Comment: ок, а как дальше вывести список изображений?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp), клик вешайте через jQuery (так кроссбраузерно).
В функции-обработчике `this` является элементом по которому был клик.

---

Смотрите методы `createElement`, `appendChild`, `setAttribute`
Можно конечно и на jQuery, но впихивать html строками - это зло